# Optimización del procedimiento transaccional en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, revisión-de-código, optimización, stored-procedure

Buenas, estoy realizando unos ejercicios y tengo resuelto el siguiente pero no logro optimizarlo más, me gustaría realizar los 6 INSERTS de forma más genérica, debo utilizar prepare statements si o sí.

Este es el enunciado.

> Ejercicio DCL_42: Crea un procedimiento nombrado premiat que dada una
>   fecha y los 7 números (los 6 del premio más el complementario) los
>   introduzca a la tabla correspondiente por el año (si la tabla no
>   existe, haz que la cree llamando al procedimiento anterior).  Ten en
>   cuenta qué si el sorteo no se celebra en jueves o sábado nos pase por
>   parámetro de salida el error 'ERROR_DI' y no haga nada.  Ejemplo de
>   ejecución: CALL premiat('2016/4/23',8,12,21,25,45,49,3,@error);

La tabla es esta.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sorteig_2016 (
            data            DATE                    NOT NULL,
            nombre          TINYINT                 NOT NULL,
            complementari   ENUM('SI','NO')         NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;);
```

Este es mi código.

```
SET @error = null;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS premiat;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE premiat(IN par_data DATE, IN par_nombre1 TINYINT, IN par_nombre2 TINYINT, IN par_nombre3 TINYINT, IN par_nombre4 TINYINT,
                    IN par_nombre5 TINYINT, IN par_nombre6 TINYINT, IN par_complementari TINYINT, OUT par_error VARCHAR(8))
BEGIN

# ERRORES -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1048 BEGIN END; -- El parámetro no puede ser nulo.
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1064 BEGIN END; -- Algun/nos parámetros son incorrectos.

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1146 -- La tabla no existe.
    BEGIN 
        CALL taula(YEAR(par_data)); -- Crea la tabla.
        /* Activo recursividad */ SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 254;
        CALL premiat(par_data, par_nombre1, par_nombre2, par_nombre3, par_nombre4, par_nombre5, par_nombre6, par_complementari, par_error);
        /* Desactivo recursividad */ SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 0;
    END;

# CÓDIGO --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF (WEEKDAY(par_data) = 3 OR WEEKDAY(par_data) = 5) THEN -- Si la fecha cae en jueves o sábado.
    SET par_error := 'ERROR_DI';
ELSE
    START TRANSACTION;
        SET @_sentencia_base =  CONCAT(CONCAT('INSERT INTO sorteig_',YEAR(par_data),' '), 'VALUES (', CONCAT("'", par_data, "'"));

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre1,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre2,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre3,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre4,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre5,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_nombre6,',\'NO\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;

        SET @sentencia = CONCAT(@_sentencia_base,',',par_complementari, ',\'SI\');');
        PREPARE consulta FROM @sentencia;   EXECUTE consulta;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE consulta;
    COMMIT;
END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL premiat('2016/4/22', 8, 12, 21, 25, 45, 49, 3, @error);
CALL premiat('2016/2/21', 8, 12, 30, 40, 45, 60, 2, @error);
CALL premiat('2016/3/20', 10, 12, 30, 40, 45, 60, 1, @error);
CALL premiat('2016/2/19', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 5, @error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ojala te sirva. Es obligatoria que la crees tu tabla con esos datos?
Quizás seria interesante crearla de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sorteig_2016 (
    data    DATE NOT NULL,
    nombre  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    num1 INT NOT NULL,
    num2 INT NOT NULL,
    num3 INT NOT NULL,
    num4 INT NOT NULL,
    num5 INT NOT NULL,
    num6 INT NOT NULL,
    complementari INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

y en tu procedimiento al momento de hacer insert solo harías 1 y ya no los 7 que te consumen un poco mas de tiempo, y sabes que el numero complementario es el campo con nombre complementario. reduces 7 inserts a 1
Espero te ayude un poco. 7 filas de información a 1.